# Asp Core Ajax Post with ViewModel

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an Asp Core Project and trying to Ajax post a filepicker blob Javascript Object back to a action to upload the image to Amazon S3. I have tried several different ways and haven't been able to get this to work. It appears to be a model binding issue. 
This functionality worked when I was only posting the image url to the action with a string parameter, but I need the filename also.

Issue: model object in action is null

Ajax Code:

```
function pickit() {
            //Start the filepicker
            filepicker.pick(
              {
                  //cropRatio: 4 / 3,
                  ////cropMin: [200, 100],
                  //cropForce: true,
                  mimetype: 'image/*',
                  //services: ['CONVERT', 'COMPUTER', 'FACEBOOK', 'FLICKR', 'DROPBOX', 'INSTAGRAM', 'BOX', 'EVERNOTE', 'GMAIL', 'PICASA', 'IMAGE_SEARCH', 'FTP', 'GOOGLE_DRIVE', 'SKYDRIVE', 'URL', 'WEBCAM', 'CLOUDDRIVE', 'IMGUR', 'CLOUDAPP'],
                  conversions: ['crop', 'rotate', 'filter', 'scale']
              },
              function (Blob) {
                  $("#imagespinner").removeClass("invisible")
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: '@Url.Action("CreateImage","Photos")',
                      contentType: 'application/json',
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: JSON.stringify(Blob),
                      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                          $("#ImageURL").val(data);
                          var img = document.getElementById("imgImageURL");
                          img.src = data;
                          $("#imagespinner").addClass("invisible")
                      },
                      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                          alertify.alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                          $("#imagespinner").addClass("invisible")
                      }
                  });


                  setTimeout(function () { $('#image-loading-message').fadeOut() }, 500);

              },
               function (FPError) {

               },
               function (FPProgress) {

               }

             );
        };
```

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> CreateImage(FilePickerViewModel model)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.url))
            {
                //Code to Upload to S3
return Json("ImageURL");
            else
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return Json("Url is needed");
            }
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class FilePickerViewModel
{
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    public String url { get; set; }
    public String filename { get; set; }
    public Int32 size { get; set; }
    public String client { get; set; }
    public String mimetype { get; set; }
    public Boolean isWriteable { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What is `Blob`? What does it look like after you stringify it?

Comment: Blob is the javascript object that filepicker returns for the uploaded image. Stringified it looks like {client: "computer", filename: "foobar.jpg", id:1,isWriteable:true,mimetype:"image/jpeg",size:12345,url:"https://foobar.com/foo"}

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, the controller action needs to have the declaration of [FromBody] since this is coming from an ajax post